# Matrix time derivative

Tags: calculus, matrices

Given a complex, square matrix $A$ that is diagonalizable, is it possible to write a simple formula for $\frac{d}{dt} A^t$ for a real, positive power $t$ and for $A$ a smooth function of $t$?

Comment: How do you define $A^s$ with $s \in \mathbb{R},s > 0$?

Comment: Edited question in response. Should have mentioned that $A$ can be diagonalized.

Comment: If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a complex eigenvalue of $A$, how would you define $z^t$ ?

Comment: The exponentiation $Y^Z$ is defined for any complex numbers except $Z,Y=0$.

$(-1)^{\pi}$ is perfectly fine. $(-1)^{\pi} = (e^{i\pi})^{\pi} = e^{i \pi^2}$ which is a perfectly good complex number.

Comment: @Benjamin I know! I just wanted to know which definition is used here because I think $Y^Z$ requires "choose" a complex logarithm (usually, the principal logarithm).

Comment: Sure. That is true, however we only need real powers (t) here so there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1, \ldots,f_n: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be $n$ differentiable functions and set 
$$D(t):\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:t \mapsto \text{diag}(f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t))$$
Furthermore let $S$ be an invertible matrix and let 
$$M(t):\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:t \mapsto S^{-1}D(t)S.$$
Then for every $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ holds
$$\frac{d}{dt}M(t)_{i,j}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{k=1}^nS^{-1}_{i,k}(D(t)S)_{k,j} = \frac{d}{dt}\sum_{k=1}^nS^{-1}_{i,k}f_k(t)S_{k,j} = \sum_{k=1}^nS^{-1}_{i,k}\left(\frac{d}{dt}f_k(t)\right)S_{k,j},$$
it follows that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}M(t)=S^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{dt}D(t)\right)S \quad \text{ with } \quad \frac{d}{dt}D(t) = \text{diag}\left(\frac{d}{dt}f_1(t),\ldots,\frac{d}{dt}f_n(t)\right).$$

Comment: This answer is not fully general. $A_t$ may not commute with itself at different time and thus $A_t$ and $A_{t^{'}}$ may not share a simultaneous eigen basis. Due to this there is not always a way to write a smooth, matrix valued function of a real number as $A_t = V^{\dagger} D_t V$ (with $D$ diag.) as you have used.

Comment: Of course, one could consider $A_t = V_t^{\dagger} D_t V_t$ instead.